# Full Text Search with SQlite3 C library with character "-" not working

Tags: c++, sqlite, wxwidgets

I have a SQLite3 database that is using FTS3. It works well in SQLite3 commandline tool but when using C library (using wxSQLite3, but that should not make difference I guess), it does not work with queries containing "-" character something like
SELECT * From Table WHERE columnx MATCH 'text1 -text2'. However, this works fine on commandline version.

I have no Idea why it does not work. All other FTS Match condition I have tried works fine.

**Note:** I have added wxWidgets to tags instead of wxSQLite3 as I cannot create new tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your databases are configured differently regarding standard/enhanced  query syntax; try `WHERE columnx MATCH 'text1 NOT text2'`.

To enable [enhanced query syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_2), compile with the [SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_fts3_parenthesis) macro.